# Python: Have an iterator iterate over log messages on a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, event-handling, python-multithreading

I have 2 threads running:

```
# Thread 1: In model
logging.getLogger('ui').info("Sit still, I'm computing...")
more_stuff = compute_stuff(stuff)
logging.info("Ok, I'm done.")

...

# Thread 2: In view, streaming messages to client
for message in log_iterator('ui'):
    send_to_client(message)
```

I want log_iterator to hang until there's a log message, and then when one comes up, do something with it.  The question is, how do you make log_iterator?  Or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some playing around, this is the solution I came up with:

```
def log_iterator(logger_names):
    '''
    Get an iterator that returns LogRecord objects whenever a log message is made.
    
    logger_names can be:
        a string identifying which logger you want to get messages iterate from
        a list identifying all the loggers you want to get messages from
        a dict<name: level> where level identifies the minimum loggling level 
            you want (default is INFO)
    '''
    if isinstance(logger_names, str):
        logger_names = {logger_names: logging.INFO}
    elif isinstance(logger_names, (list, tuple)):
        logger_names = {name: logging.INFO for name in logger_names}
    
    log_message_event = threading.Event()
```

;you should use items() because iteritems() was deprecated

```
    for logger_name, log_level in logger_names.iteritems():
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.addHandler(FireOnLog(log_message_event, log_level))
    
    while True:
        log_message_event.wait()
        record = log_message_event.record
        log_message_event.clear()
        yield record
        
        
class FireOnLog(logging.StreamHandler):
    '''
    Custom loghandler that fires an event every time a log message 
    comes in.  To use, you need to add this handler to a logger.
    '''

    def __init__(self, event, log_level = logging.INFO):
        '''
        Event is a threading.Event object
        log_level is the minimum logging level you want
        '''
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)
        self._event = event
        self._log_level = log_level

    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelno >= self._log_level:
            self._event.record = record
            self._event.set()
```

It behaved correctly when tested with the following code:

```
def _print_messages():
    print 'Started Printing loop'
    for log_record in log_iterator(['testlog', 'anotherlog']):
        print '%s:%s:%s' % (log_record.levelname, log_record.name, log_record.message)
    

def test_log_handling():
    
    t = threading.Thread(target = _print_messages)
    t.start()
    
    time.sleep(.1)
    logging.getLogger('testlog').critical('Message!')
    logging.getLogger('anotherlog').critical('Another Message right away')
    logging.getLogger('badlog').critical("Someething useless that you don't want to hear")
    time.sleep(.1)
    logging.getLogger('testlog').critical('Another Message after some wait')
```

It does seem like this is very generic functionality that python would have a builtin for, so if anyone knows how to do this with builtin functions please respond and I will give you a point!

Answer (score 1):

You can write logs to file by 1 thread. Second thread can read the file and shows logs.

This is logging configuration:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example') # set logger
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # set logger level

fh = logging.FileHandler('path-to-log-file') #set Handler
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO) #set Handler level

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s') # set log format
fh.setFormatter(formatter) # add format to Handler

logger.addHandler(fh) # add Handler to logger
```

In my example function *rewrite* logs to another file:

```
def print_message():
    for i in range(0,1000):     
        f = open('path-to-log-file', 'r')
        s = f.read()
        f.close()
        f2 = open('path-to-log-file2', 'r+')
        f2.write(s)
        f2.close()
        time.sleep(.2)

import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=print_message)
t.start()
logger.error('error message1')
logger.error('error message2')
logger.error('error message3')
t.join()
```

So logger write logs to file by first thread and second thread reads logs from file.
I think that this is what you want.

Also if you want to avoid writing logs to file you can make own Handler which send log exactly to second thread. I think that it could be complicated but I poorly know threading.

Here is logging documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

Comment: This works, but it's also possible to do it so that the receiving thread is event-driven and doesn't have to poll for log messages, and without using files - see other answer.